# What's a word to refer to "school homework" and "take-home work"?

Tags: word-request

So, we have homework that they give you in high school and university. Then we have take-home work which they give your in an office or any workplace.

Is there a word that you can use to refer to these two types of home assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homework) seems that you can use just "homework" for both

Definition of **homework**

1. piecework done at home for pay
2. an assignment given to a student to be completed outside the regular class period
3. preparatory reading or research (as for a discussion or a debate)